# How to Check List Contains with multiple values in Linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In my application I have a problem with a query.

I am trying to run a query with multiple condition values.

```
IQueryable<DealsDetails> DD = (from D in DbContext.Deals
                                        where lst.Contains(D.DealCategory) 
                                        select D);
```

I have this query and lst will contains these values like:

```
lst.Add("Other");
        lst.Add("Services");
```

And D.DealCategory contains value like this.

```
Other,Beauty,Services
Beauty,Services,
Services
Other,
Beauty
Other,Services
```

I need all those rows from table which contains Any item of that list. Means All rows which contains Other and Services.

Result is

Other,Beauty,Services
    Beauty,Services,
    Services
    Other
    Other,Services

Excluding beauty row.

Please suggest me how i write this query.

**First Edit**

I need all those rows which DealCategory Column contains any items from list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a join with your two lists, and return only elements from the first list :

```
IQueryable<DealsDetails> DD = from D in DbContext.Deals
                              join C in lst
                                on D.DealCategory equals C
                              select D;
```

**Edit:** As @Muhammad said, this won't work since the deals are in the Db and lst is in memory, but I'll let a modified answer there if you can filter the lst items directly on the server :

```
IQueryable<DealsDetails> DD = from D in DbContext.Deals
                              join C in DbContext.DealCategories
                                on D.DealCategory equals C
                              where [Clauses to filter Cs]
                              select D;
```

Comment: How can I always forget about this "limitation" :-S I guess I always work with DB OR inmem, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks For reply but this not what i want.